# Why does my code not work if I switch the position of commented line on top of the function? It's a memoization recall statement

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm trying to memoize this unique paths grid problem. Until now, I always put the memoized return statement on top of the function. But here, it's not working. I don't understand why.

Do those positions matter sometimes? Can you please explain the reason?

I have just started dynamic programming.

```cpp
int grid(long long i, long long j, long long m, long long n, vector<vector<long long>> &memo) {
    if (memo[i][j] != -1) return memo[i][j]; // but not working here, WHY??
    if (i == m - 1 && j == n - 1) return 1; 
    if (i >= m || j >= n) return 0;
    // if (memo[i][j] != -1) return memo[i][j]; // works here
    memo[i][j] = grid(i + 1, j, m, n, memo) + grid(i, j + 1, m, n, memo);
    return memo[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Are `m` and `n` supposed to be the dimensions of the two-dimensional vector `memo`?  In that case you really want `if (i >= m || j >= n) return 0;` first so that you do not attempt to access out of bounds when `i,j` are out of range.

Comment: Define "not working" exactly. What behavior are you expecting, and what are you observing instead? Also, where and how do you allocate memory for the `memo` vector? You can't index into non-existing memory.

Comment: Statements in C++ don't magically happen all at once.  Changing the order of statements in a function usually changes the order of some set of operations.  Doing a set of operations in a different order can change the net effect, particularly if results from one operation are used by a subsequent operation.   So, yes, changing the "position" of a statement among other statements can change whether the function "works" or not.      You haven't specified the criteria for "working", nor have you described what the inputs are, so nobody can guess what the reasons are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
int grid(long long i, long long j, long long m, long long n, vector<vector<long long>> &memo) {
    // delete the first statement
    if (i == m - 1 && j == n - 1) return 1; 
    if (i >= m || j >= n) return 0;
    if (memo[i][j] != -1) return memo[i][j];
    memo[i][j] = grid(i + 1, j, m, n, memo) + grid(i, j + 1, m, n, memo);
    return memo[i][j];
}
```

In here, you check that `if (i >= m || j >= n)` first, to prevent out-of-bounds error, before you try to access `memo[i][j];`

But:

```cpp
int grid(long long i, long long j, long long m, long long n, vector<vector<long long>> &memo) {
    if (memo[i][j] != -1) return memo[i][j]; 
    if (i == m - 1 && j == n - 1) return 1; 
    if (i >= m || j >= n) return 0;
    // delete the second statement
    memo[i][j] = grid(i + 1, j, m, n, memo) + grid(i, j + 1, m, n, memo);
    return memo[i][j];
}
```

In here, you try to access `memo[i][j];` first, before you check `if (i >= m || j >= n) return 0;`, so an out-of-bounds error could happen here, and you get *undefined behaviour*.